# Sample launcher Application is not launching in android

Tags: android, android-launcher

Hi I am creating one sample launcher application for Android. But When running my sample launcher application am getting error like **"Unfortunately, SimpleLauncher has stopped."**

I Strongly feel that this error is may be because of something wrong with my manifest file, so I am attaching my manifest file, Please help me to solve the problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:stateNotNeeded="true"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".AppsListActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        >
    </activity>

</application>
```

Comment: Can you please post a logcat

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: This is one of the error in logcat.

12-02 17:40:36.370    4862-4862/com.example.ganesh.simplelauncher E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.ganesh.simplelauncher, PID: 4862
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ganesh.simplelauncher/com.example.ganesh.simplelauncher.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Answer (score 0):

This **edited manifest** works as just fine..unless you wanna do some fancy stuff in your app.

```
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity
    android:name=".AppsListActivity"/>
```

**your styles.xml**

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: after changing the edited manifest also Am getting same error & same logcat error as mentioned in previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Your Logcat mentioned that you need to use an AppCompat theme.
Go to your `styles.xml` and change the `AppTheme` to `Theme.AppCompat`